# JQueryMobile - styles not applied in Webview (Android)

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, android-webview

I'm making use of "JqueryMobile" for building my android app. The problem I'm facing is that JQueryMobile styles are not getting applied for the page..

Here is the code of my HTML page (in Webview)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title></title>

<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="home" data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header"><h1>Categories</h1></div>
  <div data-role="content">
    <h2>Select a Category Below:</h2>
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
        <li><a href="#category-items?category=animals">Animals</a></li>
        <li><a href="#category-items?category=colors">Colors</a></li>
        <li><a href="#category-items?category=vehicles">Vehicles</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

and below is the code in my Activity class,

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

Any pointers on how to resolve it??

Comment: What you have should be working, if the css is at assets/www/css/styles.css

If that's the case could it be that the css simply doesn't correspond to your HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found out the problem..

I was testing my app in the emulator which is Android 4.0.. It seems "Ice cream sandwich" is not supported by JQueryMobile and hence even the major features are not working properly.. Today I tested the same app(without any code modifications) in Android 2.3.3 and it worked like charm :)

It took almost 2 days for me to figure this out :( posting it here for the sake of others :)

Comment: Accept your answer, so that its not anymore in unanswered questions' list :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried jQM 1.1.0 final?  I notice you're using jQM 1.0.0 in your code above.  Ice Cream Sandwich is supposedly supported in jQM 1.1.0 final.  From the jQM site:

"Android 4.0 (ICS)  – Tested on a Galaxy Nexus S. Note: transition performance can be poor on upgraded devices"

Answer (score 0):

Look this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10420027/1538975

The problem occurs in ICS. Just add this css code and everything works fine (I had the same problem today).

```
.ui-page {
    /* Supposed to reduce flickering, but screwed up Ice Cream Sandwich. */
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```