# content disappears with jquerymobile (video demonstration)

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am writing a mobile app using jquery mobile.  I cant seem to figure why content within the `div data-role='content'` disappears on Android 4.03+.  On iOS Safari and Chrome for Android there is no issue and everything works fine.  Its just the default Android browser this happens in.  Notice that when i tap inside a listview everything becomes visible, but once i tap outside the input to remove focus, it all disappears again. The headers and footers are set like this:

```
<header data-role="header" data-id="myheader" data-tap-toggle="false" data-position="fixed">

<footer data-role="footer" data-id="myfooter" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
```

Any ideas?  Video showing what i mean: [click me](http://youtu.be/KDCNnOl8Xps)

**edit**: I originally said everything within the `data-role='content'` would disappear, but looking again, i notice the inset listview's border is still showing.

**edit 2**:  Ive also noticed that if i remove the `data-position="fixed"` from the header and footer, the issue goes away.

Comment: Try using [Adobe Shadow](http://success.adobe.com/en/na/sem/products/shadow.html) to see what happens to the styling on the elements in real-time. Probably some class gets added due to `data-position='fixed'` that causes your elements to not show. Shadow's the best way to find out

Comment: cool little tool.  Unfortunately it showed that the css was exactly the same in my chrome desktop browser as my Android browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by re-arranging my css files in the html head.  I put all the jqm files last in load order.

Comment: I had a similar issue where a checkbox and button was showing up at first after I transitioned to the page.  Then a few seconds later they would disappear.  Using weinre I compared the CSS at runtime to that of an iOS run and they were the same.  Simply putting the JQM CSS at the end of my one large CSS file solved the problem.  WEIRD!

Answer (score 4):

Another possible solution could be the CSS fix for flickering.

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416065/why-does-my-jquery-mobile-app-not-show-correctly-in-the-android-4-0-3-browser).

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like this?

```
  <html>
  <head>
     [your css]
     [jquery css]
     [jquery mobile css]
  </head>
  <body>
  ..
  </body>
  [scripts]
</html>
```

?